# FETCHing from Custom Cursor to Collection

Tags: types, plsql, oracle11g, cursor, fetch

This feels like it should be a simple thing, but I can't seem to get this to work correctly. I have an existing procedure (`HDT_CORE_GETDATA_LSR_V31`) that returns a custom cursor built with the following code:

```
TYPE CORE_REC IS RECORD 
      (
           OrgID CHAR(20 BYTE)
           , DistrictCode VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
           --52 other fields
           , ReqSource VARCHAR2 (1020 BYTE)
      );

 TYPE CORE_REC_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR RETURN CORE_REC;
```

I'm trying to build a new function that will call this procedure and `INSERT` the result into a table.

I built the new procedure with variable, `RecordLoad`, that is a collection based on the type:

```
create or replace TYPE HDT_CORE_REC_V31 FORCE AS OBJECT 
      (
           OrgID CHAR(20 BYTE)
           , DistrictCode VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
            -- Same 52 other fields; meticulously matched to be exact
           , ReqSource VARCHAR2 (1020 BYTE)
      );

create or replace TYPE HDT_CORE_REC_TABLE_V31 IS TABLE OF HDT_CORE_REC_V31;
```

Inside the new proc, I built two variables:

```
    LSRData HDT_CORE_MAIN_V31.CORE_REC_CURSOR;
    RecordLoad SABASC02.HDT_CORE_REC_TABLE_V31 :=   
      SABASC02.HDT_CORE_REC_TABLE_V31();
```

Then I tried the following:

```
  BEGIN

  SABASC02.HDT_CORE_GETDATA_LSR_V31(LSRData, NULL, ParamOrgCode,'d', NULL,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

LOOP
  FETCH LSRData BULK COLLECT INTO RecordLoad;
  EXIT WHEN RecordLoad.COUNT = 0;

  FOR indx IN RecordLoad.FIRST .. RecordLoad.LAST
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AssociateID = ' || RecordLoad(indx).AssociateID);
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

But, this line of code: `FETCH LSRData BULK COLLECT INTO RecordLoad;` throws the error `PLS-00386: type mismatch found at 'RECORDLOAD' between 'FETCH' cursor and 'INTO' variables.`

Clearly there's a mismatch here, but I'm not sure how to resolve. I've checked and double checked that all the fields between the two constructors match exactly in name, order, and datatype.

What am I missing?

Comment: try commenting out blocks of fields to isolate the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CORE_REC` record type and the `HDT_CORE_REC_V31` object type are not the same type even if they have the exact same field and attribute lists.  As such you can't bulk collect from the cursor returning the specified record type into a collection of object types.

Instead you need to bulk collect the records in to a record type collection.

For this to work you'll need to add a declaration similar to the following to your `HDT_CORE_MAIN_V31` package spec:

```
TYPE CORE_REC_TABLE IS TABLE OF CORE_REC;
```

Then replace references to `SABASC02.HDT_CORE_REC_TABLE_V31` with `HDT_CORE_MAIN_V31.CORE_REC_TABLE`.

If you really need to work with object types instead of record types, you can create object type instances from the record type with code similar to this:

```
declare
  obj_type HDT_CORE_REC_V31;
  ...
begin
  ...
  obj_type := HDT_CORE_REC_V31( rec_type.OrgID
                              , DistrictCode
                              --52 other fields
                              , ReqSource);
  ...
end;
```

You could even create a cursor that returned object type instances by surrounding the column list with the object type constructor as similar to this:

```
select HDT_CORE_REC_V31( rec_type.OrgID
                       , DistrictCode
                       --52 other fields
                        , ReqSource) obj_tpe
  from your_table;
```

However, to work with a cursor of the above query, you would need a different cursor type declaration along the lines of `TYPE CORE_OBJ_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR RETURN HDT_CORE_REC_V31` (note: untested).

Comment: Thanks @Sentinel! Your post put me onto a slightly way to code the same solution. You are correct in that the root cause are that the two datatypes I was using were not literally the same despite being constructed very similarly. So, I changed the code declarations to: `LSRData HDT_CORE_MAIN_V31.CORE_REC_CURSOR; RecordLoad HDT_CORE_MAIN_V31.CORE_REC;` This allowed me to `FETCH` and load records into a table with an `INSERT` statement.